# What are the possible reasons that a deep learning model runs slower on GPU than running on CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, theano

My GPU which is Titan X should have be faster than the CPU which is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2643 v3 @ 3.40GHz. But two of my models runs a little slower on the GPU. One model runs much faster on the GPU. Among those two models, one is implemented with tensorflow, the other is implemented with theano. The common character of the two models is they all belong to hierarchical Bi-LSTM model which means the last outputs of the bottom Bi-LSTM are fed into the other as inputs. So neither of the models are too simple. 
So I would like to inquire what are the possible reasons that they run slower on GPU thant on CPU?

Comment: What is the gpu usage reported by the `nvidia-smi`? Maybe the code is not utilizing gpu enough?

Answer (score 0):

I could provide some info for the theano side:

Theano has been having multiple issues with `scan`, which is its workhorse for RNN loops.

Here's some of them:

1. Since theano does not know shape information at compile time, the resulting compiled routine can be suboptimal (like using `gemv` for vector-vector dot).
2. (as of Nov 2016) The current version of `scan` is implemented in cython, which have some overhead over a pure C++ version. If the RNN don't have much computation density on a single step, this can be significant.
3. It does not pipeline well. Using a `scan` to implement a map operation can often slower than using the underlying operation directly. Apparently the optimizer is premature and still can't recognize this kind of problem.

Solution:

1. Try upgrading to dev version. They have been making various improvements overtime.
2. Try unrolling the RNN (using a plain loop to build graph instead of `scan`), if you can afford the compilation time.
3. <del>I made a [PR](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/5257) to address `gemv` issue, only for old GPU backend. Give it a try (if not merged yet).</del> Now it's part of dev master branch.